# SSIS FOREACH: Remove data from SQL Table if filename already present

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, foreach, ssis

apologies if I've phrased this terribly. I only started using SSIS today.

I've written a FOREACH which loops through all the files in a folder, and updates my table f_actuals together with the filename without the extension - this filename is a combination of a PeriodKey and Business Unit. It works well.

However, this is intended to be a daily upload from our system for the entire month for each business unit (so the month-to-date refreshes daily until we close that period), so what I really need is the FOREACH to include something which does the following: -

- Checks the filenames due for import in the designated folder against the filenames already in the f_actuals table
- Removes all the matches from the f_actuals table
- Continues with the FOREACH I've already built

I know this is probably a massively inefficient way to do this (preference would be daily incremental uploads), but the files need to be month-to-date, as our system cannot provide anything else easily.

Hope this makes sense.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an Execute SQL Task within the For Each Loop to do this.

You can either use an SQL statement:

```
DELETE
FROM f_actuals
WHERE filename = ?
```

Or perhaps a stored procedure (accepting your filename as a parameter and doing the same thing as the statement above), e.g.:

```
EXEC DeleteFromActuals ?
```

For each filename in your loop, you would store this in a variable, and pass the variable as a parameter in the Execute SQL Task (this is what the `?` is).

To map the parameter in the Execute SQL Task, go to 'Parameter Mapping', and add a new parameter. Select the variable containing the filename from the dropdown list, choose a data type of `VARCHAR`, and set the 'Parameter Name' to 0. The 'Direction' should be 'Input', which is the default.

Comment: Many thanks Chris, I will try to get this working on my return to work!

Comment: For anyone reading with a similar problem, the first solution worked perfectly - using my existing filename parameter for the data upload also mapped to the Execute SQL command to remove the duplicates. I also added a File System Task to my FOREACH to move the new files to an archive folder and replace the duplicates. Since the whole thing is dependant upon how the files are named by the users, I'm assuming a similar approach could be used to validate the filenames against another table (in this case my Calendar dimension table) before import to ensure the files are correctly named.